# How to access/read kafka topic data from flink?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to read kafka data from flink and as I am new to kafka and flink, I don't know how to connect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink provides Kafka connector. In order read data from Kafka topics, first you need add Flink -Kafka connector dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Next you simply invoke Streaming execution environment and add Kafka source. Here is a sample

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");  
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
DataStream<String> stream = env
 .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(),properties))
.print();
```

That's it. You are all set to consume data from Kafka topic.

The complete code is available for download at this [link](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/blob/master/chapter02/flink-streaming/src/main/java/com/demo/flink/streaming/StreamingJob.java)