# How to print kafka topic data in Flink program?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I created a topic via this instruction:

```
C:\kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1>.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test < C:\User11\Desktop\Data.csv
```

Then I tested the topic had that data correctly. After that, I wanted to print the topic in the Flink program.My program is this:

```
 try{
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    DataStream<String> stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("test", new SimpleStringSchema(),properties));

           stream.print();
    env.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I got this INFO(because the INFO is too long I had to write some of it):

> [main] INFO org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment - Running job on local embedded Flink mini cluster
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster - Starting Flink Mini Cluster
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster - Starting Metrics Registry
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster - Starting RPC Service(s)
>   [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster - Starting high-availability services
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer - Created BLOB server storage directory C:\Users\user11\AppData\Local\Temp\blobStore-a02ff126-35cc-4c1b-b300-8689d19ff5d2
>   [main] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:57907 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000

Also, I saw this link too and It did not solve my problem:
[How to access/read kafka topic data from flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972417/how-to-access-read-kafka-topic-data-from-flink?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Would you please tell me what the problem is here?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's working to me... You may need to tell Flink to read from the beginning of the topic https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, by adding this line I can print whole contents of the topic: " myconsumer.setStartFromEarliest();" how can I access contents of the topic line by line?

Comment: Or process method https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/

Comment: Thank you very much @cricket_007

Comment: By the way, I would suggest upgrading your Kafka server version, or at least using `FlinkKafkaConsumer010`

Comment: There is no "Flinkkafkaconsumer010" to import. Would you please tell me how I can upgrade my kafka server version in the Flink program? Thanks.

Comment: The Kafka Server means download the newest (or just newer) version from the Kafka website. And you can read the Flink documentation where it tells you what to import in Maven for working with specific Kafka versions

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I have downloaded "kafka_2.11-2.0.0" for windows; but I cannot import it in the Flink program.

Comment: `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` should still work with newer Kafka servers

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, I will use "flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. First, I fulled Kafka topic with this command:

```
/home/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.32.0.2:9092,10.32.0.3:9092,10.32.0.4:9092 --topic flinkTopic < transactions2.csv
```

Then, using this code , I could print Kafka topic:

```
 final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
 StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", 
 "10.32.0.2:9092,10.32.0.3:9092,10.32.0.4:9092");
 prop.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> myConsumer= new FlinkKafkaConsumer<> 
  ("flinkTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(),prop);
    myConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(myConsumer);
    stream.print();
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
```

I hope it was useful for others.